# Change Button color onClick

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, global

I want my `Button` to change color every time I click on it. But it only changes color on the first click.

I believe the problem is in the `setColor` function. Every time I click on the `Button`, `count` gets set to 1. So even when I set it to 0, it gets reset to 1 on the next click. How do I fix this? Are there global variables in javascript/html where this would easily be solved?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
function setColor(btn, color){
    var count=1;
    var property = document.getElementById(btn);
    if (count == 0){
        property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
        count=1;        
    }
    else{
        property.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00"
        count=0;
    }

}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="button" id="button" value = "button" style= "color:white" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010')";/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, move var count=1 to before the function and it will be global.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are indeed global variables in javascript. You can learn more about [scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript), which are helpful in this situation.

Your code could look like this:

```
<script>
    var count = 1;
    function setColor(btn, color) {
        var property = document.getElementById(btn);
        if (count == 0) {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
            count = 1;        
        }
        else {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00"
            count = 0;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

1.

```
function setColor(e) {
  var target = e.target,
      count = +target.dataset.count;

   target.style.backgroundColor = count === 1 ? "#7FFF00" : '#FFFFFF';
   target.dataset.count = count === 1 ? 0 : 1;
   /* 

   () : ? - this is conditional (ternary) operator - equals 

   if (count === 1) {
      target.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00";
      target.dataset.count = 0;
   } else {
      target.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
      target.dataset.count = 1;
   } 
   target.dataset - return all "data attributes" for current element, 
   in the form of object, 
   and you don't need use global variable in order to save the state 0 or 1
  */ 
}


<input 
  type="button" 
  id="button" 
  value="button" 
  style="color:white" 
  onclick="setColor(event)"; 
  data-count="1" 
/>
```

2.

```
function setColor(e) {
   var target = e.target,
       status = e.target.classList.contains('active');

   e.target.classList.add(status ? 'inactive' : 'active');
   e.target.classList.remove(status ? 'active' : 'inactive'); 
}

.active {
  background-color: #7FFF00;  
}

.inactive {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

<input 
  type="button" 
  id="button" 
  value="button" 
  style="color:white" 
  onclick="setColor(event)" 
/>
```

[([conditional (ternary) operator])](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

[`Example-1`](http://jsbin.com/yicufi/1/edit?html,js,output)

[`Example-2`](http://jsbin.com/yicufi/2/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Every time `setColor` gets hit, you are setting count = 1. You would need to define `count` outside of the scope of the function. Example:

```
var count=1;
function setColor(btn, color){
    var property = document.getElementById(btn);
    if (count == 0){
        property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
        count=1;        
    }
    else{
        property.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00"
        count=0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, try this.
if your button id is say id= clickme

```
$("clickme").on('çlick', function(){

  **$(this).css('background-color', 'grey');
.......
```