# Change button-color when clicked

Tags: javascript, php, css, button, colors

I have tried for couple of days now to find a way to change the color of my button when clicked in javascript or PHP. I already have a button with the CSS: `#btnMenu`. 
This is the button:

```
<a href="/?nav=home"><input id="btnMenu" type="button" value="Hjem"/></a>
```

The button is: `background-color: grey;` 
 
When it's clicked, I want the button to be: `background-color: red;`

I think that it can't be done in CSS but can I change the background i javascript og PHP?

Comment: href and input? plus, you do now that `/?` looks for the index at the root.

Comment: Yes i know but anyway... It works :p

Comment: *"It works"* - if it works, then why the question? lol plus, not enough code

Comment: the button works but i cant change the background-color when clicked!!

Comment: when you click the button it will goes to that link then what is the need of changing color.? and where it will reflect?

Comment: again, not enough code to provide a solution

Comment: Becouse the button is fixed to the page. There is always 5 buttons on the left side of my page!

Comment: use css `:active` psuedoclass. like this: `#btnMenu:active{ background-color:grey; }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Button color onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937424/change-button-color-onclick)

Comment: Have a look on the solution below This problem is because after clicking on button page is getting refreshed...

Comment: you asked and people have answered. take your pick from answers given below and accept it to mark yours as solved

Answer (score 3):

jQuery is pretty easy to use to do things like this. PHP (being server side) isn't designed for making changes to the page after it has loaded.

You can try something like this:

```
$('#btnMenu').click(function(){
   $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: This question is not tagged [jquery]

Comment: Thets true but Thank you. I will try that one :) Could you at the same time try to explain me what jQuery is? The short answere?

Comment: "jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. It makes things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works across a multitude of browsers." - From the jQuery Website. You'll need to load the jQuery library, either from your own site or from a CDN.  @A1rPun, you are right - it's not tagged as jQuery.

Comment: @A1rPun still, question is unclear. Plus, OP did tag as javascript, which is what jQuery is.

Comment: @Fred-ii- JavaScript !== jQuery. jQuery is written in JavaScript but that doesn't mean that you need to use a library do to someting trivial.

Comment: @A1rPun had the OP written something like: *"I don't want jQuery solutions...."*, then I'd agree. The question is open, far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The OP didn't know about jQuery so he couldn't know. I could provide a .NET solution because he didn't ask for it.. that's not how SO works. I just want to prevent a dependancy for something really simple.

Comment: @A1rPun sure, I'll agree and you have a point there. However, a jQuery solution is still an option, nonetheless.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Cool, I think I have to accept that jQuery is taking over the world ;)

Comment: @A1rPun Lordie, I found it the best thing since sliced bread when that came out and was right there when it did. I did away from using Flash when it did.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a `a` and `button` is a good combination. However, you can use this code to change background color of button.

```
document.getElementById('btnMenu').onclick = function(){
 this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('btnMenu').onclick = function(){
 this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" id="btnMenu" value="Hjem" style="color:white" onclick="setColor()"; />

 var count = 1;
function setColor() {
    var property = document.getElementById(btnMenu);
    if (count == 0) {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
        count = 1;        
    }
    else {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00"
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

JavaScript:

```
    var count = 1;
    function setColor() {
        var property = document.getElementById('btnMenu');
        if (count == 0) {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
            count = 1;        
        }
        else {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00"
            count = 0;
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
<input id="btnMenu" type="button" value="Hjem" onclcik="setColor();"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

html

```
<a href="/?nav=home"><input id="btnMenu" type="button" value="Hjem"/></a>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('btnMenu').onclick = function(){
 this.className = 'blueColor';
}
```

css

```
.blueColor{
    background:blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/826fhe99/2/

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `a` (anchor) for a button so after clicking page will be refreshed so in such case to change color of button you should try this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<a href="/?nav=home"><input id="btnMenu" type="button" value="Hjem"/></a>

<script>
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}



  $(document).ready(function(){

          var param = getParameterByName('nav');
          if(param == 'home'){
              $('#btnMenu').css("background-color", "red");
          }

})
</script>
```