# changing button color with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, action

> i want my button to change color on click [suppose black],but on page refresh i dont want it to change its color back to original color.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .button {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2>CSS Buttons</h2>



    <input type="button" class="button" value="Input Button">

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It's not possible to do __just__ with JavaScript.

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't use jQuery? it would be really easy using jQuery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Button color onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937424/change-button-color-onclick)

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
/* On load of the page we are calling this function which will
 give us the color name stored in our local storage */
        function changeColor() {
            var color = localStorage.getItem("colorName");
            document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
/*This function will change the color of button on click*/
        var i = -1;
        function colorArray() {
            var arr = new Array();
            arr[0] = "Red";
            arr[1] = "Orange";
            arr[2] = "Green";
            arr[3] = "Blue";
            i++;
            if (i > arr.length - 1) {
                i = 0;
            }
/* We have an array with the color names, you can add any 
number of colors in this array */
/* After fetching the color from array we are storing 
it in the local storage of our browser for future use*/
            localStorage.setItem("colorName", arr[i]);
            document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = arr[i];
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="changeColor()">
    <button onclick="colorArray()" id="color"> Change Color </button>
</body>

</html>
```

[Click here for Live Demo and complete source code](http://www.dreamscoder.com/examples/javascript/Styling/javascriptbuttononchange.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you get an element with JavaScript, you can access a bunch of properties of this element.
There is **two solutions** to modify his properties :

- modify the css property (`myElement.style.myProperty = 'myNewValue'`)
- modify the class list (`myElement.classList.add('myClassName')`)

**Update after author edit :**

You could call a function `onclick="..."` on the button.
The function will add a class to this button to change his style.
Then store on your localStorage, or on a session, or on a cookie or in your database the state of the button with a boolean (clicked = true for example).
Next time you visit the page, add a check onload to add this class on this button if clicked == true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use local storage to preserve the color after the page refresh.

```
window.onload = function(){

    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

    if(localStorage["bg-color"]){
        btn.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.getItem("bg-color");
    };

    btn.onclick = function(){
        if(!localStorage["bg-color"]){
            localStorage.setItem("bg-color", "yellow");
        };
        btn.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.getItem("bg-color");
    };
    // remove from storage localStorage.removeItem("bg-color")
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies to store the state of the color between page reloads, here is a basic example.

```js
function setColor(color){
  document.querySelector('#button').style.background = color
  document.cookie = `color=${color};`
}

function getColor() {
  return document.cookie.split('; ')      // ['color=blue']
    .reduce((acc, x) => {
      const [ key, value ] = x.split('=') // ['color', 'blue']
      acc[key] = value                    // { color: 'blue' }
      return acc
    })
    .color
}

// run the functions on page load
window.addEventLister('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  setColor(getColor())
})

setColor('#bada55')
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>CSS Buttons</h2>
<input id="button" type="button" class="button" value="Input Button">
```

Comment: if the user deletes the cookies of the browser,all the data will b lost.can u suggest any other way it sets the property of the permanently even after refreshing the page.

Comment: only if you store it in a database somewhere.