# Change Color onClick

Tags: javascript, colors, styles

I am trying to change the color of an element using `.style.color` and it isn't going very smoothly. My goal is for it to change red and then blue on clicks. Any recommendations?

```
var turns = 0;

function dot_01() {
    if (turns === 0) {
        turns++;
        document.getElementById("dot_01").style.color = 'red';
     } else if (turns === 1) {
        turns--;
        document.getElementById("dot_01").style.color = 'blue';
    }
}

<div class="dot" id="dot_01" onclick="dot_01()"></div>
```

Comment: what does smoothly mean for you?

Comment: it isnt working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Button color onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937424/change-button-color-onclick)

Comment: Marking this as dupe of the first search result for the title, given that the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26937544/5734311) addresses OP's issues perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `.style.backgroundColor` to change the button color.  `.color` is going to change the font color.

```html
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#000'; this.style.color = '#FFF';" />
```

Comment: Question, any way to shorten it instead of saying document.getElementbyId, I know you can use variables, please demonstrate.

Comment: Yes.  You can put the element in to a variable.  `let elm = document.querySelector("#testitem");`  Then you can interact with the variable `elm` as if it were the element.  `elm.style.backgroundColor = '#ACD';`

Comment: Doesnt seem to work ;/     let d1 =  document.querySelector("dot_01");            d1.style.backgroundColor = '#e22b2b';

Comment: What you wrote works perfectly for me.  I would check two things.  Possibly your browser does not support using `let`.  In this case, you can change that to `var` and it should work.  If it does not work, be sure that an element with the ID "d1" definitely exists on the page you're running this.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to change the background color try `style.backgroundColor` like the following way:

```js
document.getElementById("dot_01").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
function dot_01(el) {
  if (el.style.backgroundColor === 'red') {
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';   
  }
  else el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

```html
<div class="dot" id="dot_01" onclick="dot_01(this)">Container</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this to change styling, it's a very simple JavaScript that changes the display and height properties of the CSS to show / hide a container.
Sorry I haven't changed it to your desired outcome yet but I hope this helps, just modify it to change the color by doing something like:

style="color:red"

https://jsfiddle.net/raydekker/u821a84d/

```
style="color:red";
```